# SOQL, Salesforce, Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com, soql

I am obviously missing something obvious, i'm trying to execute an SOQL query in some APEX code on Salesforce but this query just doesn't work, and i can't work out why, can somebody assist?

```
SELECT Id,Name,Amount,R2_Job_Ref__c,R2_Shipping_Post_Code__c,Shipping_Postcode_2__c
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Shipping_Postcode_2__c != R2_Shipping_Post_Code__c AND R2_Shipping_Post_Code__c != null
```

Thanks!

Gareth

Comment: What error are you getting?  Also, can you show your exact syntax (the query is usually placed within brackets which leads me to believe you're not showing your full code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

According to http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm:

> You must supply a native value—other field names or calculations are not permitted.

I think you have two options:

1. Create a formula field that returns a value that you can filter
2. Remove the clause and then filter it in memory (e.g. looping through the data and building a new data set)

Comment: Boo, well that's all rather inefficient. Ok, will have to use an if loop on the resulting data. Thanks!